# Zend Framework 3 Migration / View Helper override

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework3

I want to overwrite the function openTag from the Zend Form Helper Class, but they doesn't find my aliases? They always use the standard form helper not my helper class. Can anyone helps me?

```
'view_helpers' => [
  'aliases' => [
       'form' => Base\Form\View\Helper\Form::class,
    ],

    'factories' => [
        Base\Form\View\Helper\Form::class => InvokableFactory::class
  ],
],
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163691/understanding-grid-layout-in-zend/55195132#55195132

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787320/how-to-register-custom-form-view-helper-in-zend-framework-3/51821109#51821109

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register custom form view helper in Zend Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787320/how-to-register-custom-form-view-helper-in-zend-framework-3)

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: Can you show your application.module.php -> module-list order

Comment: This almost certainly has to do with the order of the Modules as defined in module.config.php (in your config directory). A module at the end of the config will overwrite a module before it.
As @GautamRai is requesting, the module-list order can tell us a lot. If that does not give us the answer, the total config (use $serviceManager->get('Config') to get it) can help us as well.